# Make an Android library with optional assets

Tags: android, android-library

**Background**

I'm making a library of components that will be used to build Mongolian vertical script apps. Because of Unicode rendering issues, I need to include a Mongolian font with the library. For some apps this is enough. But for other apps, a few fonts are needed. Including these extra fonts significantly increases the size of the library.

**Aim**

I would like it make it as easy as possible for developers to exclude the extra fonts if they don't need them in their project.

**Related**

I saw that there are ways to remove unneeded resources from a library:

- [Remove not needed resources from android library in apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821583/remove-not-needed-resources-from-android-library-in-apk)
- [removing unused assets from 3rd party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706395/removing-unused-assets-from-3rd-party-library)

However, these are things the developer has to figure out. From the perspective of the library creator, is there anything I can do to make this a very simple implementation for the developers using my library?

**Possible solution**

I could, of course, have two different versions of the library which are identical except for the number of resources. But this "solutions" sounds like bugs waiting to happen.

**Things I've read**

- [Building your own Android library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library) (Codepath)
- [Create an Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) (Android documentation)
- [How to create a library project in Android Studio and an application project that uses the library project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849841/3681880)

I see something in the documentation about "[non-default variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#publish_multiple_variants)". This looks promising but I don't understand how/if this works for including/excluding resources.

**Update**

I'm including the dependency section of the build.grade files for the library and a demo-app that uses the library.

build.gradle (Module: mongol-library)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

build.gradle (Module: demo-app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile project(":mongol-library")
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

These links also look like they will be helpful:

- [Multi flavor app based on multi flavor library in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)
- [android-library with specific Product Flavors dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107908/android-library-with-specific-product-flavors-dependency)
- [Gradle: add dependency for a specific flavour of the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389091/gradle-add-dependency-for-a-specific-flavour-of-the-library)
- [Product Flavors for Android Library](https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2#.51ijjyunw)

Comment: Maybe I've understood your question wrong, but can't u just use flavors?

Comment: @YuriiTsap, You probably didn't understand it wrong. I will study more about how to use flavors.

Comment: Post your gradle file and I'll provide a sample if u want. Here's a link which could help u - https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-providing-build-variant-depending-fonts

Comment: That looks like a good link, @YuriiTsap.